# C++ Downloading File with Pause/Resume controls

Tags: c++, download

Is there a **simple** library that I can use to download files **Asynchronously** from the internet with pause/resume controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention OS you use. In case of Linux/Unix you can use libcurl. This library is pretty simple in usage and powerful at the same time. It has curl_easy_pause method that does pausing and unpausing of current connection. Please see details at http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_pause.html. [Here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) you can find examples of working with libcurl.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I will use it for a Linux system. Please see my edit, I forgot to mention about "Asynchronously" can I do that with libcurl?

Comment: @mohamede1945 Wouldn't make sense to have pause/resume if you couldn't do it asynchronously would it?

Comment: Yeah, sure! But I the easy interface is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

For c++ you may see my library sample : [main.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/curlwork/source/browse/trunk/demo/download_file/main.cpp)